# Find list items in excel sheet with Python

Tags: python, excel, smtp

I've the following code below which finds non-blank values in Column J of an Excel worksheet.  It does some things with it, including getting the value's email address in column K.  Then it emails the member using smtp.

What I'd like instead is to get the person's email from a Python list, which can be declared in the beginning of the code.  I just can't figure out how to find the matching names in column J in the worksheet per the list, and then get the resulting email address from the list.

Please excuse any horrible syntax...this is my first stab at a major python project.

```
memlist = {'John Frank':'email@email.com',
           'Liz Poe':'email2@email.com'}

try:
    for i in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
        if i.endswith(".xlsx") or i.endswith(".xls"): 
            workbook = load_workbook(i, data_only=True)

        ws = workbook.get_sheet_by_name(wsinput)
        cell_range = ws['j3':'j7']
        for row in cell_range: # This is iterating through rows 1-7
                #for matching names in memlist
                for cell in row: # This iterates through the columns(cells) in that row
                    value = cell.value
                    if cell.value:
                        if cell.offset(row=0, column =-9).value.date() == (datetime.now().date() + timedelta(days=7)):
                            #print(cell.value)
                            email = cell.offset(row=0, column=1).value                            
                            name = cell.value.split(',',1)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my attempt at an answer.

`memlist` is not a `list`, rather it is a `dict` because it contains `key : value` pairs.

If you want to check that a certain key exists in a `dict`, you can use `dict.has_key(key)` method.

In `memlist` , the name is the `key` and the corresponding email is the `value`.

In your code, you could do this:

```
if memlist.has_key(cell.value):  # For Python 2
    if ... # From your code
        email = memlist[cell.value]
```

In case you're using Python 3, you can search for the key like this:

```
if cell.value in memlist:  # For Python 3
```

See if this works for you as I couldn't fully comprehend your question.

Comment: I am using Python 3.5 so I believe the has_key doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Shubham,
I used a part of your response in finding my own answer.  Instead of the has_key method, I just used another for/in statement with a subsequent if statement.

My fear, however, is that with these multiple for's and if's, the code takes a long time to run and maybe not the most efficient/optimal. But that's worthy of another day.

```
try:
for i in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if i.endswith(".xlsx") or i.endswith(".xls"): 
        workbook = load_workbook(i, data_only=True)

        ws = workbook.get_sheet_by_name(wsinput)
        cell_range = ws['j3':'j7']
        for row in cell_range: # This is iterating through rows 1-7
                for cell in row: # This iterates through the columns(cells) in that row
                    value = cell.value
                    if cell.value:
                        if cell.offset(row=0, column =-9).value.date() == (datetime.now().date() + timedelta(days=7)):
                            for name, email in memlist.items():
                                if cell.value == name:
                                    #send the email
```